# PIC mcu gets programmed but doesn't get executed

Tags: microcontroller, pic, programming

I am using 'pickit2' through Mplab to burn my code. Suddenly none of the codes (even blinking led) that I fuse through it gets executed.

I confirmed whether it writes the hex code properly using the 'Read Memory' feature. On comparison, I found no change in the hex.

I changed lot of IC's (16f/18f), I tried other boards too, but nothing worked.

What's going wrong with my setup? please help me to figure it out.

Comment: I find the issue very strange.. i am running out of time.. help me at the earliest.. thanks in advance..

Comment: Sounds like an MCLR issue.

Comment: The hex comparison suggests that you didn't change the build type, but anyway, be aware that if you burn a debug build (in contrast to a release build), it will not start running by itself, even when you disconnect the PICkit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the configuration fuse options, that you are using the correct ones for your hardware. Specifically the clock type (internal rc, external crystal) etc matches your hardware because it sounds like the chip is not running.

Comment: And it worked!! Spent some time on configuration Bits - Settings."Crystal-XT" and "Power-Up on Timer Enable Bit" were the culprit.. Thanks a lot.. But it leads to my next question - Why does the settings in the Mplab Change randomly??

Comment: @Vicky, Hmm, I've had MLAB settings change on me too. Might be due to opening a different workspace. Hopefully these settings will be stored per project and not per workspace when they release MPLAB X. Either way, open a new question if you want others to see it.